# matToolTip Not working in Angular mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular with Angular Material 16x.  matToolTip does not show at all.  I have tried many versions of the below, including a simple matTooltip="hello world", but can't get it working.  I did read where you can't place a matTooltip inside of an ng-container, but then see examples of it.  Any idea what is wrong?

```
--my component
<mat-card class="mat-form-field">
    <mat-card-content>
        <table
          style="width: 100%"
          mat-table
          matSort
          matSortActive="created"
          matSortDisableClear
          matSortDirection="asc"
          [dataSource]="dataSource"
          multiTemplateDataRows="true"
        >

<ng-container matColumnDef="statusDot">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <img
            src="../../../assets/images/Basic_green_dot.png"
            alt=""
            matTooltip="tooltipTpl"
            style="width: 15px; height: 15px"
        />
    </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #tooltipTpl>
    <div style="background: gray">
    <div>This is a template!</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100, 1000]"></mat-paginator>
</mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the official [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) it tells us that the input expected is of type string, so mat-tooltip has no support for templates. We can only provide tooltip messages as string.

> @Input('matTooltip') message: string
>
> The message to be displayed in the tooltip

So you can just pass a string instead!

css

```
.custom-tooltip-class .mdc-tooltip__surface {
  background: red !important;
}
```

html

```
...
<img
                src="https://placehold.co/600x400"
                alt=""
                matTooltip="This is a template!"
                matTooltipClass="custom-tooltip-class"
                style="width: 15px; height: 15px"
            />
...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jn7rlz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Answer (score 1):

Importing `MatTooltipModule` for your component usage should solve that issue.

Comment: It is in app.module.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've used MatTooltip, you can't pass an elementRef, but just a string. Correct me if I'm wrong!

I assume you're seeing "tooltipTpl" as tooltip when hovering. To achieve the styling you're applying in the `<ng-template>`, you could add a class to the matTooltip according the docs like so:

```html
<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        matTooltipClass="example-tooltip-uppercase"
        aria-label="Button that shows a red tooltip"
        class="example-button">
  Uppercase-tooltip Action
</button>
```